# Using FontAwesome inside a ReactJS component

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, font-awesome

I'm trying to use FontAwesome inside a ReactJS Functional Component. React component is using FontAwesome icons like `<i class="fas fa-download"></i>`:

```js
import React, { useCallback, useState, useRef } from "react";

export default function Daw() {
  return (
    <>
        <div class="btn-group">
                <button type="button" title="Download" class="btn btn-download btn-outline-primary">
                    <i class="fas fa-download"></i>
                </button>
        </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

I have installed FontAwesome:

```sh
npm install --save @fortawesome/fontawesome-free
```

## Import

When I import like this:

```js
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css'
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/v5-font-face.min.css'
```

I receive these errors:

> media.css:1          GET
> http://127.0.0.1:8088/css/home/mediacms.io/mediacms/frontend/node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts/fa-solid-900.woff2
> net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
>
> media.css:1          GET
> http://127.0.0.1:8088/css/home/mediacms.io/mediacms/frontend/node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts/fa-brands-400.woff2
> net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
>
> media.css:1          GET
> http://127.0.0.1:8088/css/home/mediacms.io/mediacms/frontend/node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts/fa-solid-900.ttf
> net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
>
> media.css:1          GET
> http://127.0.0.1:8088/css/home/mediacms.io/mediacms/frontend/node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts/fa-brands-400.ttf
> net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

[image: Screenshot: errors]

## Tried

I studied this post:

https://fontawesome.com/docs/web/setup/host-yourself/webfonts

I cannot figure out why my import is *not* working. Why fonts are not found? They are installed alongside `@fortawesome/fontawesome-free`. So, what's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually, the `next/script` package came to rescue. Implemented like this:

```js
import React, { useCallback, useState, useRef } from "react";

import Script from "next/script"; // ** This one solved the problem :)

export default function Daw() {
  return (
    <>
        <Script
            src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/xx88888888.js"
            crossorigin="anonymous"
        />

        <div class="btn-group">
                <button type="button" title="Download" class="btn btn-download btn-outline-primary">
                    <i class="fas fa-download"></i>
                </button>
        </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It may need many CSS and JS libs.

Install the packages:

```sh
npm install --save @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core
npm install --save @fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons
npm install --save @fortawesome/react-fontawesome
```

And import like this:

```js
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: I tried but it didn't work. Thanks.